# Finding the real part of a complicated complex expression

Tags: simplifying-expressions, complex, assumptions

I've the following code:

```
FullSimplify[
 Re[-(((1/((1/(1/(I*(2*Pi*f)*x))) + (1/(R)))))/((1/((1/(R)) + (1/(R + 
              I*(2*Pi*f)*L)) + (1/(I*(2*Pi*f)*
               L1 + ((1/((1/(Rc)) + (1/(1/(I*(2*Pi*f)*x))))))))))))], 
 Assumptions -> 
  R >= 0 && L >= 0 && L1 >= 0 && x >= 0 && Rc >= 0 && f >= 0]
```

But it does give an output with `Re` in the function, but I only want the real part. How can I update my code?

It gives this:

[image]

Comment: "But it does give an output with Re in the function, but I only want the real part."  So what's the problem?

Comment: @DavidG.Stork I do not think so. If you want to take a look in my edited question, you can see what I mean.

Comment: "I do not think so" does not answer my question to you.  Don't think *what*?  I urge you to speak with a native English speaker so you express your ideas properly.  We can't help you otherwise.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you need `ComplexExpand`

```
a = ComplexExpand[
  Re[-(((1/((1/(1/(I*(2*Pi*f)*x))) + (1/(R)))))/((1/((1/(R)) + (1/(R +
                I*(2*Pi*f)*L)) + (1/(I*(2*Pi*f)*
                L1 + ((1/((1/(Rc)) + (1/(1/(I*(2*Pi*f)*x))))))))))))]]
```

> -(1/(R^2 (1/R^2 + 4 f^2 π^2 x^2))) - 1/((4 f^2 L^2 π^2 + 
>       R^2) (1/R^2 + 4 f^2 π^2 x^2)) + (
>    4 f^2 L π^2 x)/((4 f^2 L^2 π^2 + R^2) (1/R^2 + 
>       4 f^2 π^2 x^2)) + (
>    4 f^2 L1 π^2 x)/((1/R^2 + 4 f^2 π^2 x^2) (1/(
>       Rc^2 (1/Rc^2 + 4 f^2 π^2 x^2)^2) + (2 f L1 π - (
>         2 f π x)/(1/Rc^2 + 4 f^2 π^2 x^2))^2)) - 1/(
>    R Rc (1/R^2 + 4 f^2 π^2 x^2) (1/Rc^2 + 4 f^2 π^2 x^2) (1/(
>       Rc^2 (1/Rc^2 + 4 f^2 π^2 x^2)^2) + (2 f L1 π - (
>         2 f π x)/(1/Rc^2 + 4 f^2 π^2 x^2))^2)) - (
>    4 f^2 π^2 x^2)/((1/R^2 + 4 f^2 π^2 x^2) (1/Rc^2 + 
>       4 f^2 π^2 x^2) (1/(
>       Rc^2 (1/Rc^2 + 4 f^2 π^2 x^2)^2) + (2 f L1 π - (
>         2 f π x)/(1/Rc^2 + 4 f^2 π^2 x^2))^2))

`ComplexExpand` will assume everything is real unless you state it is complex. 
Looks better in output form:

[image: Mathematica graphics]

I don't think using `Simplify` will get a shorter expression.